# Pass Internet over phone line

Tags: networking, internet

I recently moved-in to a new place all wired with phone lines (there is a phone plus in each room). The thing is I don't have a land line so I thought I could use that network to pass Internet throughout the house.

I have read that 100mbps Internet uses only 4 pins, and since a phone line is composed of 4 wires, I tried connecting the "active wires" (1, 2, 3, 6) to the phone network. It didn't work, and after many troubleshooting, I realized that if only one of the 8 cable wasn't connected no connection would be detected neither by the PC nor the modem.

My question: is it indeed possible to pass Internet connection over 4 wires, and if so, how?

Thank you

Comment: Did you check this? http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/21941

Comment: You may have to reverse the transmit and receive pairs.  Its called a crossover cable.  transmit has to goto recieve and vice-a-versa.  Note:  Because phone line has even less shielding that CAT5 your speeds maybe lower.

Comment: Depending on the wiring itself, you might not get close to 100mbps.  Why not just go Wireless or Power-over-Ethernet?  They are much faster and more reliable.

Comment: Is the phone cable twisted pairs or quad cable?

Comment: The wires are twisted pairs. But the problem isn't even the phone wires yet. I tried connecting the modem to the PC with an ethernet wire that had its blue and brown pairs cut out, and it didn't even work. The question is how to establish a connection with only four wires. When I can do that, then I'll look at the phone wires

Comment: Did the cable work before you cut the pairs to test?  Also can you visibly confirm the cable was made with standard color coding?  I bought 100 really cheap 3' cables once that were crazy wired.. Not even consistent with each other, only a few of the 100 actually worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, legacy residential telephone wiring is wrong for Ethernet in copper grade (voice grade Cat3 or worse, often untwisted), wiring topology (multi-tapped bus, not star), and often the number of wire pairs available.

A group called the Home Phoneline Networking Alliance (HomePNA) created a technology for doing residential LAN networking over residential telephone wiring, but it could never keep up with Ethernet because it had to deal with the unfortunate reality of preexisting residential telephone wiring. I believe the HomePNA efforts got merged into the ITU's G.Hn, and so HomePNA lives on as an optional physical layer for G.Hn.